# With Google Script how do I transfer cell values from one sheet to another sheet's open cell values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to design a Google sheet that takes the responses from a Google Form's sheet and transfers the "values only" to a different Google sheet. The values have to be transferred cell by cell since the information gathered goes to different cell locations. The destination sheet has more columns than the response sheet so more information can be put into the destination sheet as a work job progresses. I am making my Google sheet public for input the main sheet is [Testing Grounds](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rq8McolIJwoQRE99kCCHfQDfRE1xY0rg3XCZa1c7t2A/edit?usp=sharing), I need the "Form Responses Sales" sheet cells to transfer to the "Job Status " sheet certain cells. I the script I have created so far has a variable designated for each cell. This is what I have created so far, the top variables are to be used as counters, I had this working slightly but I can not seem to get it to import now. I tried using a trigger built into Google script that ran the function onEdit. I am ok with all edits to the script on the currently shared sheet. Thank for any and all answers to what may be a simple problem.

```js
var resCount = 1;
var resRow = 0;
var pastTime = 0;
var jobCount = 2;
var jobRow = 0;


function createJobStatus() {
 //Response Refrence Variables
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheetName = "Form Responses Sales";
   var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  var rowRange = sourceSheet.getActiveRange();
  var responRow = rowRange.getLastRow();
  var getRow = [];
  getRow = responRow + resCount;
Logger.log(responRow);
Logger.log(getRow);

  //Sales Report Response Variables

      var Timestamp = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,1);
      var salesShipDate = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,23);
      var salesResponse1 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,2);
      var salesResponse2 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,3);
      var salesResponse3 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,4);
      var salesResponse4 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,5);
      var salesResponse5 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,6);
      var salesResponse6 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,7);
      var salesResponse7 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,8); 
      var salesResponse8 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,9); 
      var salesResponse9 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,10); 
      var salesResponse10 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,11); 
      var salesResponse11 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,12);
      var salesResponse12 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,13);
      var salesResponse13 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,14); 
      var salesResponse14 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,15); 
      var salesResponse15 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,16);
      var salesResponse16 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,17);
      var salesResponse17 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,18);
      var salesResponse18 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,19);
      var salesResponse19 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,20);
      var salesResponse20 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,21);
      var salesResponse21 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,22);
      var salesResponse22 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,24);
      var salesResponse23 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,25);
      var salesResponse24 = sourceSheet.getRange(getRow,26);


  //Job Status Variables 

   var destinSheetName = "Job Status ";
   var destinSheet = ss.getSheetByName(destinSheetName);

   var destinRowRange = destinSheet.getActiveRange();
   var destinRow = destinRowRange.getLastRow();
   var putRow = [];
   putRow = destinRow + jobCount;
Logger.log(destinRow);
Logger.log(putRow);

      var companyNumber = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,26);
      var jobStatusB = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,29);
      var jobStatusC = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,30);
      var jobStatusD = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,31);
      var jobStatusE = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,32);
      var jobStatusF = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,33);
      var jobStatusG = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,34);
      var jobStatusH = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,27); 
      var jobStatusI = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,45); 
      var jobStatusJ = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,54); 
      var jobStatusK = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,63); 
      var jobStatusL = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,72);
      var jobStatusM = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,81);
      var jobStatusN = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,90); 
      var jobStatusO = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,94); 
      var jobStatusP = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,103);
      var jobStatusQ = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,112);
      var jobStatusR = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,120);
      var jobStatusS = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,130);
      var jobStatusT = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,140);
      var jobStatusU = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,150);
      var jobStatusV = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,160);
      var jobStatusW = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,25);
      var jobStatusX = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,116);
      var jobStatusY = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,117);  
      var jobStatusZ = destinSheet.getRange(putRow,164);


  if(getRow >> resRow){
    Timestamp.copyTo(companyNumber), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesShipDate.copyTo(jobStatusB), {valuesOnly:true};  
    salesResponse1.copyTo(jobStatusC), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesResponse2.copyTo(jobStatusD), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesResponse3.copyTo(jobStatusE), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesResponse4.copyTo(jobStatusF), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesResponse5.copyTo(jobStatusG), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesResponse6.copyTo(jobStatusH), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesResponse7.copyTo(jobStatusI), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesResponse8.copyTo(jobStatusJ), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesResponse9.copyTo(jobStatusK), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesResponse10.copyTo(jobStatusL), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesResponse11.copyTo(jobStatusM), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesResponse12.copyTo(jobStatusN), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesResponse13.copyTo(jobStatusO), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesResponse14.copyTo(jobStatusP), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesResponse15.copyTo(jobStatusQ), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesResponse16.copyTo(jobStatusR), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesResponse17.copyTo(jobStatusS), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesResponse17.copyTo(jobStatusT), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesResponse18.copyTo(jobStatusU), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesResponse20.copyTo(jobStatusV), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesResponse21.copyTo(jobStatusW), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesResponse22.copyTo(jobStatusX), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesResponse23.copyTo(jobStatusY), {valuesOnly:true};
    salesResponse24.copyTo(jobStatusZ), {valuesOnly:true};

 resCount = getRow + 1;
 resRow = getRow;
 pastTime = Timestamp;
 jobCount = putRow + 1 ;
 jobRow = putRow;

    }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps I can offer an alternative. First in the destination sheet, import all the responses with importrange function.  Then  in the sheet where the specific columns go, use query() function in each column to bring the data you need in the order you need. No scripting required

Comment: Where you have valuesOnly:true.  Shouldn't that be contentsOnly:true?